# How can I remove border lines when using geom_sf?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial

I tried doing the following:

```
ggplot(geography) + geom_sf(aes(fill=rate, color = NULL))
```

but that didn't get rid of the border lines.

Comment: You'll need to provide more details, such as a minimal reproducible example.  Otherwise it's unclear what "geography" and "rate" should look like.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Without a reproducible example it is difficult to know exactly what you are looking for.  However, I will take a guess that your are looking for a way to suppress the lines marking boundaries between different polygons (regions), e.g., suppress the lines showing country borders on a map of the world.  If that is so then here is a solution.

## Use `lwd = 0` in the `geom_sf` call.

Example (you *might* need to download the developmental version of `ggplot2`)

```
# devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
library(maps) 
library(maptools)
library(rgeos)
library(sf)

world1 <- sf::st_as_sf(map('world', plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))

with_boundary <-
  ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = world1, mapping = aes(fill = ID)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  ggtitle("With Country Boundaries")

without_boundary <-
  ggplot() +
    geom_sf(data = world1, mapping = aes(fill = ID), lwd = 0) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  ggtitle("Without Country Boundaries")
```

[image]

Comment: would you happen to know why `geom_sf` is using `lwd`, a `pch` parameter, instead of `ggplot2` names, it understands `alpha` for transparency....

Comment: Not sure if this is outdated, but `lwd` doesn't work for me. The following does:  `library(sf)
library(ggplot2) 

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))

ggplot(nc) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = AREA), colour = NA)`

Comment: @FonsMA Does not work for me either.

Comment: Alternatively, to `lwd = 0`, you can use `color = NA`. See this post for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59808375/how-to-get-ride-of-polygon-borders-using-geom-sf-in-ggplot2/59808487#59808487

Comment: See that FonsMA and Miao Cai says the recipe is not working. 

Depending on what your problem actually is, using 'size' instead of or in addition to 'lwd' may also be relevant.

Comment: I also found that using `alpha` in the colour argument could remove border lines of `geom_sf` objects. Like this: `colour = scales::alpha("a-color-of-your-choice",0)`. Note the alpha value is set to 0.

Comment: It looks like this got changed in some recent updates. There's now an aes() called linewidth

https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/11/ggplot2-3-4-0/