# Setting edge/border thickness using geom_sf in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I am trying to change the border colour on regions of and sf object when I plot it. Changing the colour of the border is fine, however, the lines are a bit thin so I want to make only the coloured lines thicker so they are more visible.

Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47720329/how-can-i-remove-border-lines-when-using-geom-sf) suggests that using "lwd" will allow changes in thickness. However, when I try I either get no effect or extremly thick lines.

See the example below

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot)
library(dplyr)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>%
  mutate(type= case_when(
    BIR74>16000 ~"High",
    TRUE ~"Low"
  ) %>% factor(levels = c("Low", "High"))) #the levels are ordered to avoid the grey lines overwriting the red ones

nc %>%
  ggplot(.) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = BIR74, colour = type)) + #does the job but the coloured borders are quite thing
  scale_color_manual(values = c( "#666666","#F8766D"))


nc %>%
  ggplot(.) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = BIR74, colour = type, 
              lwd = ifelse(type =="High", 1, 0.5)) #The values can be anything and it still looks rubbish
          ) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c( "#666666","#F8766D"))
```

[image]

How can I get only senible thicknesses like x% thicker? Ideally only the target edges will be changed.

Comment: Not sure where `lwd` comes from. For `ggplot` this would be `size`, and then you may need to set `scale_size_*` with a manual or some other type of scale. You can't set the values you want inside `aes`, you set them with a scale

Comment: I used lwd as they used that in the linked example. I tried with size I still end up with the same problem though. Can you make an example where one set of edges is controllably larger than the other, I don't really understand your comment.

Comment: You can put `size = type == "High"` inside `aes`. Then there will be one size for true and one size for false. Then add `scale_size_manual` (or `_discrete`) and set the values there. You can't set the exact size (or any other aesthetics) you want inside `aes`.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to use the `lwd` parameter outside of the `aes`:

```
nc %>%
  ggplot(.) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = BIR74, colour = type),
          lwd = ifelse(nc$type =="High", 1.5, 0.5)
  ) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c( "#666666","#F8766D"))
```

Good luck!

Comment: This throws an error. `lwd` seems to have been a beta version of the `size` aesthetic, but the error comes because you need to set aesthetics inside `aes`, and you need to do it without the `nc$`

Comment: ggplot2 3.4.0 replaces `size` with `linewidth` so ensure you are using that now. https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/11/ggplot2-3-4-0/