# How to get ride of polygon borders using geom_sf in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

This question has been asked before in [an old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47720329/how-can-i-remove-border-lines-when-using-geom-sf), but the accepted answer does not currently work anymore in the current version of ggplot2. Here is a minimal example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rnaturalearth)
world = ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
ggplot(world) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = pop_est)) + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma", trans = "sqrt")
```

[image]

My question is: how can I get rid of the borders in each country?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Main Solution: `color = NA`**

In `ggplot2`, borders of plotting objects are controlled by `color` parameter, you can set `NA` to the `color` parameter in `geom_sf` in order to indicate to `ggplot2` to not plot borders (actually, the border will be plot but no color will be attributed).

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rgeos)
world = ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
ggplot(world) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = pop_est), color = NA) + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma", trans = "sqrt")
```

[image]

**Alternative: `lwd = 0`**

Alternatively, you can obtain the same results by using `lwd = 0`, however according to @caldwelist's answer below, this solution is not recommended and it success will be system-dependent.

Thus, on my system, I was able to remove borders by applying `lwd = 0`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rgeos)
world = ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
ggplot(world) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill = pop_est), lwd = 0) + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma", trans = "sqrt")
```

**R Session Info**

Just to  mention that I'm using the last version of ggplot2 (3.2.1)

```r
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 19.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] rgeos_0.5-2          sp_1.3-2             sf_0.8-0             rnaturalearth_0.1.0 
 [5] lubridate_1.7.4      forcats_0.4.0        stringr_1.4.0        dplyr_0.8.3         
 [9] purrr_0.3.3          readr_1.3.1          tidyr_1.0.0          tibble_2.1.3        
[13] tidyverse_1.3.0      data.table_1.12.8    circlize_0.4.8       ComplexHeatmap_2.2.0
[17] lattice_0.20-38      ggplot2_3.2.1       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3              class_7.3-15            png_0.1-7              
 [4] assertthat_0.2.1        zeallot_0.1.0           digest_0.6.23          
 [7] utf8_1.1.4              R6_2.4.1                cellranger_1.1.0       
[10] plyr_1.8.5              backports_1.1.5         reprex_0.3.0           
[13] rnaturalearthdata_0.1.0 e1071_1.7-3             httr_1.4.1             
[16] pillar_1.4.3            GlobalOptions_0.1.1     rlang_0.4.2            
[19] lazyeval_0.2.2          readxl_1.3.1            rstudioapi_0.10        
[22] GetoptLong_0.1.8        labeling_0.3            munsell_0.5.0          
[25] broom_0.5.3             compiler_3.6.2          modelr_0.1.5           
[28] pkgconfig_2.0.3         shape_1.4.4             tidyselect_0.2.5       
[31] viridisLite_0.3.0       fansi_0.4.1             crayon_1.3.4           
[34] dbplyr_1.4.2            withr_2.1.2             nlme_3.1-143           
[37] jsonlite_1.6            gtable_0.3.0            lifecycle_0.1.0        
[40] DBI_1.1.0               magrittr_1.5            units_0.6-5            
[43] scales_1.1.0            KernSmooth_2.23-16      cli_2.0.1              
[46] stringi_1.4.5           farver_2.0.3            reshape2_1.4.3         
[49] fs_1.3.1                xml2_1.2.2              vctrs_0.2.1            
[52] generics_0.0.2          rjson_0.2.20            RColorBrewer_1.1-2     
[55] tools_3.6.2             glue_1.3.1              hms_0.5.3              
[58] parallel_3.6.2          clue_0.3-57             colorspace_1.4-1       
[61] cluster_2.1.0           classInt_0.4-2          rvest_0.3.5            
[64] haven_2.2.0
```

Comment: Your first solution does not work on the most recent CRAN version of `ggplot2`, 3.2.1, at least on my system. However, the second solution using `color = NA` works fine.

Comment: I have the version `ggplot2` 3.2.1 and both solutions works fine for me. I edited my answer to provide `sessioninfo()` of my current R session.

Comment: Interesting point to note that apparently the behavior when `lwd = 0` is system dependent and isn't recommended. Had opened up a [Github issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3744) and it was quickly closed by someone much better than me ha!

Comment: @dc37 `lwd = 0` does not work for me, but `color = NA` works. Thank you!

Comment: @caldwellst, thanks for sharing your feedback. I edited my answer accordingly to disply the `color = NA` solution first.

Answer (score 4):

Just to note, apparently usage of `lwd = 0` is not recommended, and `color = NA` as per @dc37 is the correct option. [This](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3744) response to an issue I opened for this explains why and why different users had different results:

> Setting size to 0 is not recommended as it does not necessarily remove the border. This is outside the control of ggplot2 but is up to the graphic device (hence the system dependency). The recommendation is that a lad of 0 should result in the thinnest possible line but not all devices honours that.
>
> Set colour to NA instead