# Remove strong grey from tmap in R plot

Tags: r, plot, tmap

I got this map plot from TMAP library in R but as you can see there are many dark grey areas, is there a way to smooth these areas/boundaries so I can see better what color it should be?

The map is below:

[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUE7U.png)

I read about a post thar recommend using the `lwd = 0` argument in my plotting function but I already tried and it did not work as I was expecting. My code for this plot is:

```
plotly <- dataframe %>% ggplot() + geom_sf(aes(label = name_muni, fill = Mortalidade),lwd = 0) + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "OrRd")
    
plotly <- plotly+ggtitle(title)+ xlab("") + ylab("") +theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

As you can see the lwd = 0 argument rith there. Also, can I choose the percentage of boundaries that are plotted?

Comment: Borders/boundaries in `ggplot2` are controlled by the `colour` parameter, so change `lwd = 0` to `colour = NA`. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59808487/2530121) for further infomation. Thanks